# How do I compute $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2e^{-x^2}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I arrive at the partial solution of $((x*e^{-x^2})/2)- (\pi^{1/2}/2)$ using double integration by parts.  How do I resolve the first part of the solution with e.  Is the solution even right?

Comment: I fixed the title of your question with LaTex. Please apply the same for the body of the question (it's not quite clear what you mean there with all the parenthesis).

Comment: basically a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1149907/173147 (see also the answers on the general cases)

Comment: I voted to close as a duplicate because the same process(es) needed to evaluate this integral is/are demonstrated fully in the post of which this is essentially a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 e^{-x^2} \, dx = 2 \int_0^{\infty}x^2 e^{-x^2} \, dx = 2J. $$

$\begin{align}
J &= \int_0^{\infty}x^2 e^{-x^2} \, dx\\
&= \int_0^{\infty} x d(-\frac12e^{-x^2}) = x (-\frac12e^{-x^2})\Big|_0^\infty+\frac12\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\, dx\\
&=\frac12\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\, dx\\
&= \frac{\sqrt \pi}4
\end{align}$

that gives us $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 e^{-x^2} \, dx  = \frac{\sqrt \pi}2$$